# How to parse a specifically formatted timestamp text into data that can be used for date/time arithmetic in Java code?

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, jsoup

I'm reading text from an online forum using JSoup and need, for example, all posts made over the last 24 hours. However, the timestamps from the forum posts are formatted in the following way:

"Wednesday Aug 28, 2013, 02:44 AM GMT"

What would be the best way to process timestamps formatted in the way seen above, so I could use them for processing - like as mentioned, getting only all posts made over the last 24 hours? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String input = "Wednesday Aug 28, 2013, 02:44 AM GMT";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm a z");
Date date = sdf.parse(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to parse the string into date object.

```
Date d = new Date("Wednesday Aug 28, 2013, 02:44 AM GMT");
```

This will return the date object and by comparing it with current time you can get the posts made over last 24 hrs.

Comment: You mean the format I'm currently getting is a valid string input for a Date() constructor as is?

Comment: I'm not even sure that would work. Also, that constructor has been deprecated since 1.1

Comment: Though its deprecated It still works. I tried it before post it here. No issues found.

Answer (score 1):

You may also like to have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to see how you can use patterns to parse different strings to date. It has some samples as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is fixed, `"Wednesday Aug 28, 2013, 02:44 AM GMT"`
why dont you do a StringTokeniser on the string using `" "` (space) as the token.

Then you could get an array of `"Wednesday", "Aug", "28,", "2013,", "02:44", "AM", "GMT"`

You could then get the necessary elements and check if within 24 hours.

There are some unwanted characters in the array, but i am sure you know how to remove them for checking logic.